# I want to push my form data inside a list and show it in mat-table in (using angular 12)

Tags: reactive, mat-table, angular-reactive-forms

I want to push my reactive form-data value inside a list and show it in the mat-table.
For now, my dataSource for mat-table is in this format.

> Array(1) 0:{ brand: "" color: "" description: "" image: "" item_name:
> "asd" manufacturer: "" other: "" storage: "" tax: "" type: "Goods"
> unit: "pc"}

front-end nothing is rendering only header of the table are displayed

*Ts File*:

```
itemEntryForm:FormGroup;
  imagePreview:string;
  dataSource=[]
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['type', 'name', 'description', 'unit'];
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.itemEntryForm=this._formbuilder.group({
      type           :     ['Goods'], 
      item_name      :     ['',Validators.required],
      description    :     ['',Validators.required],
      unit           :     ['pc',Validators.required],  })
  }
 addItem(){
  this.dataSource.push(this.itemEntryForm.value)
  // this.dataSource=this.itemEntryForm.value
  console.log(this.dataSource)

  }
```

HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" *ngIf="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 mx-auto">..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this instead:

```
  addItem(){
     this.dataSource = [...this.dataSource, this.itemEntryForm.value]
  }
```

This will create a new reference for the list, allowing the mat-table to pick up on the changes. Alternatively you could inject ChangeDetectorRef, and run .detectChanges() - this should do the trick as well.